# AngularJS: jQuery Steps error

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-switch

I have some 3 steps done in jQuery Steps plugin. The steps need to be changed dynamically when the URL path changes(which happens due to a navigation on same page). The dynamic change of content is brought by ng-switch. The problem is:
The first time I navigate through the page it works. I see the ng-switch default DIV but when I click the navigation which changes the URL, the page does not load again. It gives me error: "One or more corresponding step titles are missing."
Parts of code:

```
<h1>Heading
<div ng-switch on="$location.$$url">
       <div ng-switch-default>
       </div>
       <div ng-switch-when="/../../">
       </div>
</div>

<script> 
    $("#wizard").steps({
     labels: {
        finish: "Import"
     },
     headerTag: "h1",
     bodyTag: "div", 
     ..... (other things)
     });
</script>
```

Any advice?

Comment: This question again?

Comment: I thought it did not make my problem clear and understandable so deleted the old one and created this one.

Comment: Did you or did you not close the 'h1' tag?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working when I added

```
$timeout (function (){
        $scope.wizardSteps();
    },1000);
```

to the init function.